# Don't $_GET value on link rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I config enable htaccess on my server (i enable mod_rewrite and do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064005/enable-htacess-error-on-ubuntu-12-04-with-apache2)

But on localhost is run echo $_GET value php : http://oseeyou.com/test/on-localhost.png

and on server don't run: http://oseeyou.com/test/on-server.png

I don't understand this, may help me.

Thank.

Comment: 1- you want to ask your question in a better, understandable, english 2- if I understand your question, you just have a bad htaccess setup

Comment: Sorry neofutur, i not good english. In my htaccess file RewriteRule ^data/([^/.]+)/?$ data.php?id=$1 [L] .I don't $_GET['id'] on my server, but localhost is normal.

Comment: why do you add ?id=$1 ? it sould not be needed to "forward" the get data, try with a more basic rewrite rule

Comment: give more info in the question, like this rewrite rule, the exact url you want to redirect  . . . also save $_GET at the very beginning of the page, it will be emptied later

Comment: can you please show me the code of your htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

- many frameworks will empty the $_GET array
- your rewrite rule with ?id=$1 could actually empty the GET array
- also, try to change [L] to [QSA,L]

  For more have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463642/get-is-empty-when-the-url-has-variables

Comment: thank neofutur, i try your way but can't run. I will find other way config.

Comment: also make sure your server is using apache , other webservers wont necessarily support htaccess / rewrite rules / the same syntax

Comment: my server is Debian 6.0 run apache2, php 5.3.3